# what is limitation of input type text array in php.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I m dynamically generating 20 input field type of array in html and submitting record and storing in database.

For Example for particular one input field is coded as below. similar there are other 20 input fields are there.

```
<input readonly type="hidden" size="7" placeholder="Dis" id="dis" class="dis" name="dis[]" value="{{@e.less_discount}}" />
```

Now when i submit this form and check in php i m getting only first 110 record even if i have passed more than 114 records.
here is code through which i m checking count of Post data.

```
    $itemCount = count($_POST["item"]);     
    echo "itemcount".$itemCount;
    print_r($_POST);
```

Out put is

**111 items.** but i have passed 114 record from form.

[image]

it's working fine if records are less than 110. so i want to know is there any limitation of input type array in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit on the input variables in PHP is something you can configure in your .ini file, the variable you are looking for is max_input_vars. If the distinct fields contain particularly large amounts of information, you may also have to look at post_max_size.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure of few things to get to post big forms :

`max_input_vars`: By default, the maximum number of input variables allowed for PHP scripts is set to 1000.

`post_max_size` : the max size that you can post to the server.

`upload_max_filesize` : if you have files in your form, you need to increase this value too.

`post_max_size` should always be greater then `upload_max_filesize` because you don't usually post just a file or a bunch of files, but you post data too.